# Cucumber Test Step time of execution in Java

Tags: java, web-services, testing, soap, cucumber

If i have Cucumber scenario like this :

```
Scenario: Correct response should be returned.
    When User sent "xml example" request
    Then Response should have some data "
```

And for this first step in ma TestStep class :

```
@When("^User sent \"(.*)\" request")
    public void sendRequest(String requestName) throws Exception
    {
       //code for SOAP request 
    }
```

If service is not available, test will run for hours. I would like to stop it after some period of time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this service controled by you or its external service? Also which lib you are using for sending requests?

Comment: Hi. Service is not controled by me. I have my project testing framework, methods for SOAP requests are in interface so i cant see them. Interfaces are in libs.

Comment: Anyway, your lib which is using for requests should have configuration where you can pass connection timeout parameter. Main idea is extend your cucumber pattern where you can pass second param (timeout) and use it for request. From which lib these interfaces?

Comment: I understand all that, my libs are from my project from my Productivity team so implementation of some classes and methods is hiden from me, thay should (and they do have it) have timeout but for some reason, that timeout is not working. Im am here to find alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with `ExecutorService` can be used but it was not acceptable for my project. I had to override method from my lib. This is what i did:

```
   @Override
    public SOAPMessage sendSOAPMessage(SOAPMessage request) throws Exception
    {
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
        URL endpoint =
            new URL(new URL(serviceUrl), "endpoint spec.",
                new URLStreamHandler()
                {
                    @Override
                    protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url) throws IOException
                    {
                        URL target = new URL(url.toString());
                        URLConnection connection = target.openConnection();
                        // Connection settings
                        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                        connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                        return (connection);
                    }
                });

        return soapConnection.call(request, endpoint);
    }
```

so when i called `sendSOAPMessage` my test step will break down after 5 seconds if there was no response in that period of time.

Answer (score 0):

If your lib is not terminating request after provided timeout, you can use alternative approach with `ExecutorService`. The main idea is submit task with request to SOAP service to `ExecutorService` and then call `get(time, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` with timeout from Future.

Example:

```
Future<String> future = executor.submit(new SoapRequeset());
future.get(5L, TimeUnit.SECOND); //will throw exception if result not available after timeout
```